# Failing to send a bytearray via sockets in Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, file-transfer

I am trying to transfer the contents of a file via sockets.
In 90% of the time this code just runs fine, but somtimes, it fails.

The connection is not only used to transfer the files but also for an DataInputStream/DataOutputStream-Based communication between server and client.

The problem is, that bytes seem to be stuck in the streams.
The file I transmit will be broken, and the next time I transfer something (for example, an integer) the server receives something completly different from what the client sent.

Please note, that I am previously sending the size of the file via DataOutputStream.writeInt() to determine the size of the array. This seems to run fine.

This is the code to send the file on the client side.
I had previously read the file via an FileInputStream to the byte[] array

```java
public static void writeToStream(byte[] binary, OutputStream out) throws IOException
{
    int offset = 0, left = binary.length, read;
    while(left > 0)
    {
        if(left > 1024) read = 1024;
        else read = left;
        out.write(binary, offset, read);
        offset += read;
        left -= read;
    }
    out.flush();
}
```

On the serverside this code should copy the bytes from the stream into the array which will then be written to a file.

```java
public static void readToArray(byte[] binary, InputStream in) throws IOException
{
    int left = binary.length, offset = 0, read, toread;
    while(left > 0)
    {
        if(left > 1024) toread = 1024;
        else toread = left;
        read = in.read(binary, offset, toread);
        left -= read;
        offset += read;
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate your help here!

Comment: For better help sooner, post your code as an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem. This allows users to copy/paste and reproduce your issue. It's possible your issue lies in code not included in your example - show us how you read the file and how you send/read the data length.

Comment: What network protocol are you using to send the data? Are you using UDP / TCP? If you are using UDP your not guaranteed the packets will arrive? Could this be your problem?

Comment: I am using TCP. It seems as I have already found the problem by accident: There is another thread in the client that is communicating with the server. I allways assumed, that Streams in java were serial, which is not the case. by serializing all communication (making sure just one thread is using the sockets streams) this does not happen anymore now.

Comment: How do you close your questions?

Comment: Why would threads be serial? What would be the point of them?

Comment: There are multiple queues in the program that will use the outputstream to fill themselfes with data from the server, each has an own thread which is communicating from time to time. They interfered with the fileupload, which was the problem. I now modified the class holding the outputstream to allow just one thread at a time to send something through the stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any of the nonsense you have written in `writeToStream().` All you need there is `out.write(binary),` which makes the method itself basically redundant. Similarly your `readToArray()` method is just a poor imitation of `DataInputStream.readFully()` with your own bugs added. Throw it away and use that.

Comment: Thanks, even though that was not the problem, I will use that one in the future, I didn't know about it :)